# Remap OS X Option/Alt key in Windows 7 VirtualBox VM

Tags: windows-7, macos, keymap

I am attempting to use SharpKeys in Windows 7 to remap the OS X Option/Alt key, however, when I click the `type key` button, the Option/Alt key doesn't show up, it acts as if I had not pushed the key at all.

Any ideas on how I can remap the Option/Alt key in a windows 7 virtualbox vm?